# Cropping tool not working in Fabric 1.7+

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm quite new to Fabric.js and I found some fiddle that is working correctly to 1.6.7 version including. So the tool allowed me to cut the selected area of ​the photo. However, since 1.7 this function draws a path in a different location than I select on the screen. Could I ask for a clue where the cause may lie?

http://jsfiddle.net/czechue/kNEaX/852/

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c1', {
  isDrawingMode: true
});
var src = "http://fabricjs.com/lib/pug.jpg";
canvas.backgroundColor = "#333";
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = "purple"
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 4

var el = new fabric.Rect({
    fill: 'transparent',
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top',
    stroke: '#ccc',
    strokeDashArray: [2, 2],
    opacity: 1,
    width: 1,
    height: 1
});

el.visible = false;
canvas.add(el);
var object;
fabric.util.loadImage(src, function (img) {
    object = new fabric.Image(img);
    object.set({
        selectable: false
    });
    object.hasRotatingPoint = true;
    canvas.add(object);
    canvas.renderAll();
});

canvas.on('path:created', function(options) {
    var path = options.path;
    canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
    object.clipTo = function(ctx) {
      path.set({ objectCaching: false})
      path.render(ctx);
    };
    object.selectable = true;
    disabled = true;
    el.visible = false;
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i suggest since the big differences between 1.6.7 and 1.7.x, to jump directly on 2.0, but apart this i think what you need to do is to use the object as dirty after you apply a clipPath.

```
canvas.on('path:created', function(options) {
    var path = options.path;
    canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
    object.clipTo = function(ctx) {
      path.set({ objectCaching: false })
      path.render(ctx);
    };
    object.selectable = true;
    object.dirty = true;
    disabled = true;
    el.visible = false;
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```